# CANoe CAPL function: clear trace window

Tags: canoe

I'm currently trying to find a way to automate the clearing of the trace window in CANoe.

I've had a look on the help menu within CANoe but there's nothing apart from a manual x option available on the Trace window itself. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: There is no function as of yet, and no feasible workaround I know. It is for grahpical window.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update. It's just to allow em to clear the old instance of a signal on the can bus which then allows me to see when exactly a new instance of the signal appears again. I know there are delta timings on the side but I need to be able to automate the process

Comment: Well to see the chronological order with timestamps of messages (and their signals) there is the button in the Trace toolbar for it. It will list every instance of every message in chronological order.

Comment: Could you just add another trace window that filters out everything except for the signal(s) that you are interested in and then watch this trace window for signal updates?
Another option would be to program a CAPL node to watch your signal and update a panel or whatever when your signal changes.

Answer (score 2):

**Syntax**

```
void traceWindowClear(char[] windowName);
```

**Function**
Clears the contents of the Trace Window.

**Parameters**
`windowName`   - The name of the Trace Window.

**Return Values**
—

**Availability**
Since Version **11.0** In Measurement Setup and  Simulation / Test Setup.